# IE status bar. I need to add a clickable icon to the status bar

Tags: c++, internet-explorer-8, atl, bho, statusbar

My bho (Browser Helper Object) is a sidebar (right-sided iframe) that needs to be opened/closed by clicking the status bar icon in IE (IE8). I didn't find any informations for clickable icons. Anyone knows wich interface to use to do that. Thank you. (I'm using ATL: Active Template Library).
*If anyone need precisions, please ask. I'll be checking for responses every single days.*

Comment: What is a *bho*?  From the hater of abbreviations and acronyms (since they can represent many meanings that the target audience must guess at).

Comment: Sorry, i just re-edited my post. (BHO: Browser Helper Object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modification of IE's Status Bar by add-ons is not supported and is likely to cause reliability and performance problems across IE versions. You should consider using a Menu item instead, as Menu items ARE supported extensibility points.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The thing is that i found this article: codeproject.com/KB/atl/IEStatusBarPane.aspx but he is using 'CComModule _Module;' that is deprecated. I needed the same exemple but for atl. Thanks again.

Comment: The code in that article won't work by default for Vista or higher. You would get access denied because the status bar is in a process with a higher integrity level.